# How to get the value from ngxTimepicker as well as call function after select date in Angular7?

Tags: angular7

I have created a website angular7 i which i am using [ngxTimepicker] for select time.i have get the selected value after select from timepicker.i have used [(ngModel)] but i got following error in the console :

```
Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
```

tell me anyone how to use [(ngModel) 
]  with [ngxTimepicker]  and fire function after select value from model.check my below fiddle and tell what the wrong in my code?

```html
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input aria-label="default time" [ngxTimepicker]="mStartTime" [value]="'05:11 pm'"  [(ngModel)]="mStartTime" 
      (focusout)="setData()" readonly>
    <ngx-material-timepicker #mStartTime></ngx-material-timepicker>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

In the .ts file
Use this

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
@ViewChild("YOURTIMEPICKERNAME") ANYVARIABLE: ElementRef;}
```

To get the time value use:

```
onClick() {
console.log(this.ANYVARIABLE.time);}
```

ANGULAR JINDABAD!!!